# Bug with local camera function

Tags: camera, lighting, blur

I have a problem when I try to use the function local camera with lamp. The view just gets blurry. You can see it on the gif-image. Anyone come across this?

GIF: https://i.stack.imgur.com/naYY0.jpg

[image]

[image]